# How to query date per fiscal year (time in epoch)

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have an inventory database, on the database  I'm storing multiple Items with the date that the item was created.
The date is in epoch time.

What I need to do is to create a report per fiscal year - in this case from sept 1, 2020 to Aug 30, 2021, it is possible to do this query if I have the time on epoch or  it easier if  I store the date on a different format.

```
id    |    name    |    status    |    time
1     |    pens    |    active    |  1636395754
```

Comment: `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` might help

Comment: epoch times can be hard to deal with in mysql; highly recommend you just use a datetime type ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" format) and store a UTC time

Comment: Re your deleted question [see this](https://gist.github.com/ikegami/9fbbd0188d672e42381964e0c5dad770)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible using [FROM_UNIXTIME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) function. Example query:

```
SELECT *,
       FROM_UNIXTIME(time)
FROM mytable
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(time) >= '2020-09-01'
  AND FROM_UNIXTIME(time) <= '2021-08-31';
```

If you want to add a new time column in UTC format based on the existing `time` column, you can do like this (provided that you have the access privilege):

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD utctime DATETIME;
```

Then `UPDATE` the new column:

```
UPDATE mytable SET utctime=FROM_UNIXTIME(time);
```

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=081af28ffeff4d1915b977fd9e9b25a6)